# Changing a parameter in a differential equation according to a condition?

Tags: matlab, events, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to change the input wheel velocities of a mobile robot according to a position condition ?

```
if d > 0 & d < 0.4
        p.WR = 0.51;
        p.WL = 0.5;
    elseif d > 0.4 & d < 0.8 
        p.WR = 0.5;
        p.WL = 0.51;
    elseif d == 0.4
        p.WR = 0.5;
        p.WL = 0.5;
    end 
function dt = mydglw9(t,c,p)
     x = c(1);y = c(2);th = c(3);
      dx = (((p.r*p.WL)+(p.r*p.WR))/2) * cos(th);
      dy = (((p.r*p.WL)+(p.r*p.WR))/2) * sin(th);
      dth= ((p.r*p.WL)-(p.r*p.WR))/p.L;
      dt = [dx;dy;dth];
      pose = [x y th];
  end
```

however i always get the error [ Reference to non-existent field 'WL' ], is there a way to make the solver check the condition before solving the differential equations ?

Comment: your code is not complete! on which line do you get this error? –

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether o not the `WL` field from the `p` structure exists with [isfield](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html):

```
isfield(p,'WL')
```

returns `true` if the field exists.